# Index into one dataframe based on another with partial-match of column names

Tags: r, dataframe, indexing, replace, dplyr

I have two dataframes in R that contain data for an online experiment, where participants rated words on a screen. The dataframes correspond to reaction times and word ratings. I don't want to include trials for words where participants rated the word in less than 1 second.

The RT dataframe contains columns labelled by each word. E.g. "RT.word_1", "RT.word_2", etc. The second dataframe also contains columns labelled by each word. E.g. "rating.word_1", "rating.word_2", etc. In both dataframes, the rows correspond to individual participants.
[rating dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZ1EO.png)
[RT dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMlPq.png)

**I have recoded my RT dataframe so that any reaction time under 1 second is now NA. What I want to do is recode my rating dataframe such that it contains NAs at the exact same indices**. That is, I want to index into my rating dataframe by participant and word #, find out if that word's reaction is coded as NA in my RT dataframe, and also code it as NA in the rating dataframe if that's the case. I have no idea how to do this without for loops and if statements like I would use with python...Any advice would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK you have to write a loop to take care of the columns, but you can vectorize the placement of NA values.

```
ratings <- data.frame(
  rating.word_1 = c(1, 1, 4),
  rating.word_2 = c(4, 3, 3)
)

RT <- data.frame(
  RT.word_1 = c(2.360, NA, 1.328),
  RT.word_2 = c(NA, 1.719, 2.469)
)

for (col_index in 1:ncol(RT)) {
  target_rows <- is.na(RT[[col_index]])
  ratings[target_rows, col_index] <- NA
}
```

R can do this kind of computation on the left side of an assignment, which I have always felt was super bizarre, but more experienced R programmers have told me is paradigmatic.